# React js this.props.variable is undefined in child Component

Tags: reactjs

I set a minDate variable when I call the child component, which is a datePicker (doesn't matter). In the child I get this.props.minDate = undefined.

Am I missing something?

Here is my code:

**Parent Component**

```
getInitialState() {
    return {
        minDate: '',
        startDate: moment().subtract(30, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        endDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    };
},
componentWillMount() {
    ...
    this.setState({minDate: response});
    ...
},
render() {
    return (
        <DatePicker minDate={this.state.minDate} label="Start Date:"/>
    );
}
```

**Child Component**

```
getDefaultProps() {
    return {
        label: 'Date:',
        minDate: '',
    };
},

componentDidMount() {
    this.datePicker = $('#'+this.props.id);
    if (this.datePicker) {
        this.datePicker.datepicker({
            minDate: this.props.minDate
        });
    }
},
```

...

Comment: I suspect `response` is undefined in `componentWillMount()` when you are calling `setState()` perhaps you could put a console.log(response) there to see what it is.

Comment: This would only happen if you passed something undefined here `minDate={this.state.minDate}`. Did you log that out and make sure??

Comment: I get the response, and if I console.log the this.state.minDate in Parent render() part, I get the value as it should be.

Comment: @DavidSimon What is the value of `response`? It looks like when you are setting the state of `minDate` on the parent `response`  is `undefined`.

Comment: @Enijar In ParentComponent  render() function i console.log it, it logs it 4 times. First 3 times are empty, but the 4th time has the date. Is it possible, the the props in the child is set before I would actually pass the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an `undefined` `minDate` value when instantiating jQuery date picker.

Here's what is happening to the value of `minDate`:

**Parent component** sets the value of `minDate` to an empty string because it's defined so in the `getInitialState` method.

**Parent component** sets the value of `minDate` to the value of the `response` variable (probably `undefined` but I can't be sure as there is no other information to what the value of `response` is).

**Child component** takes the value of `this.props.minDate` when the child is mounted. At this point the value of `this.props.minDate` is either an empty string or `undefined`.

Finally jQuery date picker is then given the value of `this.props.minDate` in the `componentDidMount` method. The jQuery date picker is only instantiated once, so if the value of `this.props.minDate` changes over time it is not re-evaluated by the jQuery date picker.

Comment: After I read your answer, the problem seemed to be smaller than I thought.
I just need to check in Parent render() that the this.state.minDate is empty or not.
if ($.isEmptyObject(this.state.minDate)) {
     return null;
}

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The Child component has no object in state called `minDate`, the parent has however.

If you access it in your Child component through the props object it'll work unless the response in your `componentWillMount` in your Parent is undefined of course.

Furthermore, if your `minDate` property is supposed to be a Date object I would have the `defaultProps` return the same type by default.

```
getDefaultProps() {
    return {
        label: 'Date:',
        minDate: '',
    };
},

componentDidMount() {
    this.datePicker = $('#'+this.props.id);
    if (this.datePicker) {
        this.datePicker.datepicker({
            minDate: this.props.minDate,
        });
    }
},
```